# how to display the infopath dropdown based on the yes/no value in the sharepoint list - Infopath, sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am loading the Infopath dropdown values from the sharepoint document library (Title column) using SOAP Webservice, and now i want to display some of the values alone based on the [yes/no - column] in the other column of the document library.

Only i need to display the Values which is having 'Yes' in the sharepoint library column.

How to achieve this? using Manage rules?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen.L

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see...

Use Filter condition in the infopath form
1.) Go to drop down properties
2.) Click entries select XPath
3.) Click Filter data button and write the filter condition ([yes/no - column name] = YES)